# c# ssis - script component within data flow

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to parse values from a text file using c#, then append it as a column to the existing data set coming from the same text file. Example file data:

```
As of 1/31/2015

1 data data data
2 data data data
```

So I want to use a script component within an ssis data flow to append the 1/31/2015 value as a 4th column. This package iterates through several files, so I would like this to take place within each dataflow. I have no issues with getting the rest of the data into the database into individual columns, but I parse most of those out using tsql after fast loading everything as one big column into the database.

edit:

here is the .NET code I used to get it started, I know this is probably far from optimal, but I actually want to parse two values from the resulting string, and that would be easy to do with regular expressions

string every = "";

string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filename).Take(7).ToArray();

string.Join(",", lines);

every = lines.ToString();

MessageBox.Show(every).ToString();

Comment: I would take a different approach. Use the native Flat File Source and specify that it should skip the first 2 lines, which makes your header in the third line, data in fourth to EOF. Now you can use a For Each file Loop Container and process all the files. The trick then is to add a Script Task before the Data Flow, but within the FELC. It will use the path that is popped from the FELC as a read-only argument. It will update an SSIS Variable called `AsOfDate`. The script reads the first line of the file, parses out your values and assigns it. Then a Derived Column in DFT that adds AsOfDate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you happen to know the best way to take the first 5 or so lines from a text file and store them for use? I tried a lame way, using file.readlines.take(5), but then I joined them into one big string and tried a messagebox.show for testing, and the actual string didn't come up, just a generic system show message.

Comment: Click Edit and add your .NET code into the question. Both the reading and your messagebox code. Makes it way easier to diagnose your problem